# Nested loop in R with two level of variation

Tags: r, loops

Hello dear stack overflow community,

Here is the context of my problem : I have a dataframe with each column corresponding to one bat species and and each row corresponds to the acoustic activity measured for one night (for each night of recording not all the species as been sampled).

eg :

```
> Dataset
   Bba Ese Hsa Mda Mda.Mca Mema Mpu
1     3  NA  NA  NA      33   NA  NA
2    NA  NA  NA  NA       1   NA  NA
3     2   4   1  NA      19    1  NA
4    NA  NA  NA  NA      25   NA  NA
5    NA  NA  NA  NA       3   NA  NA
6     1   1  NA  NA      53   NA  NA
7     1  NA   9  NA      NA    1  NA
8    NA  NA  10  NA      NA   NA  NA
9    NA  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
10    1   1  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
11    6  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
12   12  NA   1  NA      NA    1  NA
13    3  NA   2  NA      NA    1  NA
14    1  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
15   NA  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
16    1  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
17    2  NA  NA  NA      NA    2  NA
18    1   1  NA  NA      NA   NA   1
19   NA  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
20    1   1  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
21    2  NA   1  NA      NA   NA  NA
22    1  NA  NA  NA      NA    4  NA
23    1  NA   1  NA      NA    1  NA
24   NA  NA  NA  NA      NA    2  NA
25    1  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
26    1  NA  NA  NA      NA    1  NA
27    1  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
28    5  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
29   NA  NA  NA  NA      NA   NA  NA
.....
```

To study vocal activity I am checking the quantile  of bat vocal activity per species

```
apply(Dataset[,9:15],2,quantile, na.rm=TRUE, type=7, c(0.02,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.98))
      Bba   Ese    Hsa    Mda Mda.Mca  Mema Mpu
2%   1.00  1.00   1.00   1.00    1.00  1.00   1
25%  1.00  1.00   2.00   2.00    2.00  1.00   1
50%  3.00  4.00   6.00   4.00    3.00  2.00   2
75%  9.75 12.00  18.00  12.00   20.00  4.00   6
98% 53.86 69.88 166.12 313.32  159.04 27.28  44
```

To test the impact of sampling (number of night) on my quantile estimate, I want to do a boostrap. More specifically, I want to calculate the mean of the bat activity if I take only 3 night per species using 1000 random sample with replacement. And i want to do it If I take from 3 to 70 nights.
This is what I have so far (for one species):

```
Bbana<-as.data.frame(Bbana)
L= length(Bbana[,1]) 
B= 1000 

m<-list()

for (j in 3:70) {
for (i in 1 : B) {
  idx<-sample(1:L, j, replace=TRUE)
  data_idx<-Bbana[idx, ]
  m[i]<-mean(data_idx)
}}
```

Somehow it didn't give my what I am expected : 67 list with 1000 means of bat activity.

Could anyone help me ?

(I don't know if it's clear enough...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to loops and lists:

```
for (j in 3:70) {
mat = matrix(NA, nrow = B, ncol = ncol(idx))
for (i in 1 : B) {
  idx<-sample(1:L, j, replace=TRUE)
  data_idx<-Bbana[idx, ]
  mat[i,] = colMeans(data_idx, na.rm = TRUE)
}
m[[j]] = mat
}
```

Otherwise, this option should work (and should be more efficient / convenient to use):

```
sample.fun = function(nb.nights, dataset){
  # select randomly nb.nights rows to sample 
  selected.rows = sample(1:nrow(dataset), nb.nights, replace = FALSE)
  # return a vector with their means
  return(colMeans(dataset[select.rows,], na.rm = TRUE))
}

sapply(3:67, function(nights) replicate(1000, sample.fun(nights, dataset), simplify = 'array'), simplify = FALSE)
```

This will return you a list of 67 elements that each contains a dataframe of 1000 rows (1000 means per species)

Comment: Thanks a lot glagla !
It helps me to go further with my problem. However, for your first proposition, I get a matrix with 68000 elements. What I really would like is 67 matrix (3 to 70 nights) with 1000 elements (means). Concerning you second suggestion, because I have many NA in my dataframe it's not working. I a mtrying to solve that.

Comment: sorry, I read your question a bit too fast. I corrected my answer accordingly. I think that for the NA issue, the na.rm option could fix it. Not entirely sure though as I did not test it on real data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the modification ! I change it a little bit and it's working perfectly : 

` m<-list()
for (j in 3:70) {
  mat = matrix(NA, nrow = B, ncol = 1)
  for (i in 1 : B) {
    idx<-sample(1:L, j, replace=TRUE)
    data_idx<-Bbana[idx, ]
    mat[i,] = mean(data_idx, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  m[[j]] = mat
}
`